# C++ File Handling , How to implement record not found on this code

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

How do I output using `cout` a message to user when user tries to search something that is unavailable in the data files? I have tried the following code:

```
cin>>temp;
fstream a;
a.open("Account.dat",ios::app|ios::in|ios::out);
while(a>>acno>>type>>cid>>credit>>debit>>tellid){

            if(temp==acno){
                cout<<"Customer ID : "<<cid<<endl;

                break;
            }//if not found , display an error message,I've tried using else block here
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: 5And you added the C tag because they start with the same letter? Don't spam tags of unrelated languages!

Comment: so why `else` did not work?

Comment: FiestStep - it returned only the results from first record

Comment: @Olaf There's no C tag.

Comment: @Olaf - c and c++ are not related ? :D

Comment: @GihanSandaru They are different languages. Common subset of C and C++ is small and code written in it often considered bad in both languages.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: @GihanSandaru: I did not say they are not related! Whoever thinks they are the same or C is a C++ subset does not know at least one of them well enough to write good programs in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `if - else` within the loop because this would execute every single time that the read account doesn't match the search criteria. Instead, use a variable that tracks whether or not we found something:

```
cin>>temp;
fstream a;
a.open("Account.dat",ios::app|ios::in|ios::out);
bool found = false;
while(a>>acno>>type>>cid>>credit>>debit>>tellid){

            if(temp==acno){
                cout<<"Customer ID : "<<cid<<endl;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
if(!found) {
  // display error message and exit
}
```

BTW, this is not what iostreams where intended for. Instead, use a library like Boost.PropertyTree to save data. That is going to simplify your code a lot.